# Angular Sourcemap mouse over info missing on google chrome inspect/debug mode

Tags: angular, google-chrome, debugging

when i try to mouse over the source code on chrome, the variable box is missing.

i.e. when mouse over on the line 96, on isAlertUpdate, it used to be a tool tip or box coming out. Now is nothing.

This issue happened on the chrome inspect source tab as below
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that's a known issue with Chrome 79.

Here's a thread https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22882968?hl=en

You can either try Chrome Canary or downgrade Chrome.

Comment: is chrome latest version 79 issue. Nobody working and solve it on coming Christmas

Answer (score -1):

If you install google developer edition, your issue will be solved